# GitHub API match github handle with actual commiter

Tags: git, github, github-api

Currently the GitHub API allows me to get a list of commits pushed by a particular github user, and I want to find out what are the commits that were actually **committed** by this user.

One way to do this is to ask the user to provide both **GitHub handle** and their **email address** and hope they match. But it seems too troublesome.

I also understand that GitHub `commit` API has the GitHub handle information, but to use that I need to call the APIs to verify each commit by the user, which is troublesome.

It there a way to automatically match from **GitHub handle** to their **primary email address** used for commits?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/users/emails/#list-email-addresses-for-a-user

Comment: @max360 I'm trying to get user's email without authenticating as the user.